# VueJS binding custom directives to looped components based on condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
[{name: "test-a", directive: "v-testa"}, {name: "test-b", directive: "v-testb"}, {name: "test-c", directive: "v-testc"}]
```

and I will loop through this and want a result like this.

```
<ul>
 <li v-testa>test-a</li>
 <li v-testb>test-b</li>
 <li v-testc>test-c</li>
</ul>
```

if I do something silly like this it won't work :)

```
<ul>
 <li v-for="item in list" item.directive>{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve the desired result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but need to use a different `v-bind` syntax.

You pass an object with keys being the HTML attribute name.

You can generate an object at runtime using `Computed property names` for [object initialization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Try this

```
<ul>
 <li v-for="item in list" v-bind="{[`${item.directive}`]: ''}">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the preferred way to achieve something like this is the following:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: [
      { name: "test-a", directive: "v-testa" },
      { name: "test-b", directive: "v-testb" },
      { name: "test-c", directive: "v-testc" }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>List:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="item in list" :data-directive="item.directive">
       {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Because if you start making up your own attributes, you run into two problems:

1. An HTML validator will assume that your attribute is incorrect
2. You are competing with other code which is also making up its own attributes

The data- attribute prefix has two benefits:

1. HTML validators will ignore the attribute when doing validation
2. JavaScript will gather these attributes into the special `data` object to provide easy access

So using the data- prefix allows you to work with an otherwise invalid attribute by telling the validator to ignore it.